# AMPScript Help if error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I just try to write a dynamic text field, I need to took data from a Data extention field called Toplam and I have 3 rules if the customer point is greater than 35 points I show them Option 1, if the customer point is less or equal to 35 I show them option 2 and if the customer point is equal or below 25 I show them option 3.

Why do I get the below error? How can I fix it?

**Error Message:**

> There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative. Error 2: Script IF Statement Invalid
> An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: 25 MemberID: xxx JobID: 0 Skriptblock enthält nicht erkannten Ausdruck. Skriptausdruck: 25 Mitglieds-ID: xxx Job-ID: 0 
> Invalid Content: 
> ELSEIF @Toplam THEN]%% Halen haz&#ı;r olmayabilirsiniz ama &#ş;imdiden bu geli&#ş;meleri o&#ğ;renmenizde bir sak&#ı;nca yok. %%[

```
%%[IF @Toplam > 35 THEN]%%
    Pazarlama Otomasyonu için hazırsınız.
%%[ELSEIF @Toplam <= 35 THEN]%%
    Y
Yaklaşıyorsunuz ve çok yakında ihtiyacınız olacak.
%%[ELSEIF @Toplam < 25 THEN]%%
 
Halen hazır olmayabilirsiniz ama şimdiden bu gelişmeleri öğrenmenizde bir sakınca yok.

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that could be causing this. First, have you done a lookup in a previous block to actually gather the value you are evaluating? If not, to do this use the following to get your variable:

```
%%[

var @key, @Toplam

set @key = [row_identifier]

set @Toplam = Lookup("Data_Extension_Name","Toplam","column_identifier", 
@key)

]%%
```

Another issue is that the data type you're trying to evaluate is a string and needs to be converted to an integer.  To update your value you can do that following:

```
%%[IF FormatNumber(@Toplam, D2) > 35 THEN]%%
Pazarlama Otomasyonu için hazırsınız.

%%[ELSEIF FormatNumber(@Toplam, D2) <= 35 THEN]%%

Yaklaşıyorsunuz ve çok yakında ihtiyacınız olacak.
%%[ELSEIF FormatNumber(@Toplam, D2) < 25 THEN]%%

Halen hazır olmayabilirsiniz ama şimdiden bu gelişmeleri öğrenmenizde bir 
sakınca yok.

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Hopefully that will correct your error!